# Need to update date code mm/dd/yyyy in in several webpages without using code

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

I need to get the date from the server in mm/dd/yyyy without any javascript or asp code.  I would prefer to do this as either a link that flows in the current document frame and that also injects the mm/dd/yyyy into the current html web page as css or other non code based solution.  I don't want to use any extraneous querying languages like xslt, xquery, or plinq either.

example:

```
<h3>Date:<date format="mm/dd/yyyy" src="currentdate.asp" /></h3>
```

output:

#### Date:06/26/2012

Comment: Not if I can add it on one line in a style=... in html

Comment: You must find the "`automagical`" button.

Comment: Will I am extremley lazy, one day I will buddy, until then its stack overflow and people smarter than me. ;)

Comment: What about server side includes?

Comment: Why all the restrictions?  Is this an academic exercise?  The pragmatic approach is to get some script in the ASP (or if the date originates in SQL Server T-SQL) to format the date correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as he others say you cannot achieve this without at least a bit of javascript. what you could do is use jquery to select all your date tags and then post an ajax to get the current date in your preferred format.

like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("date").each(function(index, element) {
                var d = $(this);
                $.post("ullu.asp", {
                    ajax: true,
                    act: "currentdate",
                    format: d.attr("format")
                }, function(data) {
                    d.after("<span>" + data + "</span>");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

<h3>Date:<date format="%m/%d/%Y" /></h3>
```

then on ullu.asp:

```
<%
if request("ajax") = "true" then
    dim d : d = DateTime.FormatDate(request("format"), now)

    response.write d
end if
%>
```

DateTime is here a class of mine for formatting dates you could use your own implementation... Furthermore you could add another attribute to your  tag like "src" to send your ajax there.

i know you wanted to do this without "using code" but that is not possible. with this solution you only have to add a bit of javascript which handles all your  tags...

Comment: This is very goood, but I have to update many pages and reports to include a date and time stamp and need a very simple solution.  Javascript has already been burned in so to speak on our existing code base and I don't want to step on toes across several departments.

Comment: ok i understand that but you could have included one script file which will "convert" EVERY date tag on every page... but its your choice...

Answer (score 4):

No, this is an impossible task.

HTML is a static language. It is impossible to use a static language without any dynamic element (javascript, php, ssi, etc.) and have it change the page.

You will need to find a way to loosen the constrains for your project as it is currently not only impossible but illogical.

EDIT:

I thought of one potential way but it wouldn't be pretty.

You could use an `<iframe src="date.asp">` and if the `date.asp` only returned the date then it would work. This is the only way possible.

Comment: Why down vote me for telling you the answer you don't want to hear? It is the truth.

Comment: How about a <form src=currentdate.aspx></form> can I stick a form inside a table's td element?  Or is target?

Comment: No, thats not how the `<form>` element works. See updated answer

Comment: No I want it in the same document frame if possible.

Comment: Sorry its not possible without any scripting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13082/discussion-between-secretformula-and-retrocoder)

Comment: +1 original answer is correct, the edit = scripting hence doesn't fit the original questions constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make it an `img`, then use an on the fly img generator which generates text as an image from the server.  You can use something like csImageFile for generating text in an image on the fly.

http://www.chestysoft.com/imagefile/default.asp

Your image would look like this:

```
     <img src="date.asp" />
```

Then your `date.asp` file would be generating a new image (using `response.contenttype="image/jpeg"` with the current date on each call.

But your date would be displayed as an image, not text.

Or you can use an iFrame like the secretformula's answer, or Ajax/jQuery for this.  But if you're not gathering the data from the server, then your date will from the client.

Comment: Yeah I was considering this... but I think I will do this in combination of a way to add text...  Some said to create a generated html file that has like date.html and the only thing in it is <td>6/26/2012</td> in it.  and then just using the include file...

Comment: Its hard to not use code, but your solution is probably the most eloquent in my scenario. thx